# React Native onPress triggered automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a react native app and when i render the code the onPress is automatically triggered and this causes too many renders error. i tried using an arrow function in the onPress but this didn't do anything, i'm not sure why theres so many re renderings happening also im using functional components, here's my code

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1)
  const [track, setTrack] = useState([{number: 1, text: '', trigger:false, is:false},
   {number: 2, text: '', trigger:false, is:false},
   {number: 3, text: '', trigger:false, is:false},
   {number: 4, text: '', trigger:false, is:false},
   {number: 5, text: '', trigger:false, is:false},
   {number: 6, text: '', trigger:false, is:false},
   {number: 7, text: '', trigger:false, is:false},
   {number: 8, text: '', trigger:false, is:false},
   {number: 9, text: '', trigger:false, is:false},
   {number: 10, text: '', trigger:false, is:false}])
   
  const nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   
  function WhenPress(val){
   
    const elementsIndex = track.findIndex(val =>
       val.number == 1 )
    let newArray = [...track]
    newArray[elementsIndex] = {...newArray[elementsIndex], is:
       true}
    setTrack(newArray)
    return(console.log('it worked'))
  }
 

   const m = track.map((val) => 
 <View   key={val.number}  style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'center', marginTop:10}}>
   <TouchableOpacity style={{color:'white'}}>
     <Text style={{fontSize:20 ,color:'white', borderWidth:1, borderRadius:100, borderColor:'white', paddingLeft:9, paddingY:4, paddingTop:3, height:35, width:35}}>{val.number}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
   <TextInput style={{borderRadius:7, borderWidth:1, height:35, width:110, color:'white', borderColor:'white', marginLeft:20}}/>
 
   {console.log(Object.values(val))}
   
   {val.is ? 
   <View style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row'}}>
   <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'red', width:80, height:35, marginLeft:30}}><Text>switch</Text></TouchableOpacity>
   <TouchableOpacity  style={{ backgroundColor:'white', width:35, height:35, display:'flex', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', borderWidth:2, borderRadius:7, borderColor:'white', marginLeft:60}}><Text style={{fontSize:40}}>+</Text></TouchableOpacity>
   </View>:
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => WhenPress(val)} style={{marginLeft:170, backgroundColor:'white', width:35, height:35, display:'flex', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', borderWidth:2, borderRadius:7, borderColor:'white'}}><Text style={{fontSize:40}}>+</Text></TouchableOpacity>
   }

  </View>
  )
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:40, }}>Tracking</Text>
      <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:12, marginBottom:5 }}>THURSDAY 31st August</Text>
      <View style={{width:'100%', height:30, backgroundColor:'orange', alignItems: 'center', display:'flex'}}>
      <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:15}}>TRIGGERS</Text> 
      </View>
      

      <View style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:'center'}}>
        {m}
      </View>
      
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    
  },
});
```

Comment: You are mutating state in your `WhenPress` function. Even though you clone the outer array, the element objects are still references so changing the object mutates the state before you call `setTrack`. You can instead call `setTrack(prevTrack => {...state change logic});`

Comment: hey pilchard after taking your advice the app works however when i click the button i get an error saying undefined is not an object 'track.map'                                                                      heres the line i replaced the setTrack with setTrack(prevTrack => {newArray})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you clone the `track` array using destructuring, the nested objects are still references to the original objects stored in state. Thus, when you call `newArray[elementsIndex] = {...newArray[elementsIndex], is: true};` you mutate the `track` state array.

You can avoid this by passing a callback to `setTrack` which will implicitly pass the previous state for you. You need to move all your mutations inside this callback and have them act on `prevTrack` rather than `track`. Something along these lines...

```
function WhenPress(val){
  const elementsIndex = track.findIndex(val => val.number == 1 );
       
  setTrack(prevTrack => {
    prevTrack[elementsIndex] = {...prevTrack[elementsIndex], is: true};
    return prevTrack;
  });
  
}
```